# Change URL Breeze looks for MetaData

Tags: metadata, breeze

Breeze is looking for my Metadata at `api/entities/Metadata`, however it's actually being published at `api/$metadata`.  How can I tell Breeze to look in the right location?

Comment: And it's returning as xml, not javascript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up the dataservice with this seems to have worked...at least I get metadata now

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('/odata/'); //path to service
```

Comment: Yes of course you have to tell Breeze where to get your metadata from when you set it up - please refer to the docs in the future - http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-metadata-details

Comment: Actually, I don't "specifically" tell it where to get the metadata, the issue was it was looking in the wrong place because it wasn't configured properly for OData.  No need to be rude in the comments.

Comment: Actually, you do.  When you are using Breeze you have to tell the entity manager what service to use to get the data.  Whether you are using EF, OData, or some random service, you still need to let Breeze know where to get your data from (there are some configuration defaults it will try to use if you do not set it up)  As I noted, all of this is in the docs - http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata

Comment: ugh, whatever, I had the service location set, but it was looking for `/Metadata` instead of `/$metadata` because it wasn't setup as OData `breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });`

Comment: Yes, CaffGeek, it was a matter of selecting the appropriate dataservice adapter. As soon as I saw that you were looking for an endpoint with "$metadata" in the URL, I would have guessed that this was the problem. Someone unfamiliar with the OData dataservice might think you were looking for some kind of unusual web api endpoint in which case you'd want to do some other route manipulation (on client or server). What we have here is "[a failure to communicate](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oik6dXm-0l0)". We're all in this together :-)